# How can I detect which tikzmark version I'm using?

Tags: overleaf, tikzmark, versions

With `\listfiles` we can easily list the current version of all the packages loaded.

But it doesn't tell anything about the version of the TikZlibrary `tikzmark`.

How can I detect it?

The problem is, in particular, when I'm using Overleaf and I can't find the version using a distribution tool like `texdoc tikzmark` or similar.

MWE:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    Something with \tikzmarknode{A}{TikZ Mark}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[<-, red] (A) -- ++(1,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

File list in the log:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
     pgf.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
   expl3.sty    2019-01-28 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-01-28 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2019-01-28 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
l3keys2e.sty    2018-10-17 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
  xparse.sty    2018-10-17 L3 Experimental document command parser
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: by looking in the dtx source, the docu or by  asking the author to put some version info in the file ;-)

Comment: I supposed that all TikZ libraries would have the same version as TikZ, in your case, 3.1.1.

Comment: Do you get the version for *any* Ti*k*Z library? What does `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}` give you? @Sigur No, the libraries are by different authors. `tikzmark` is by LoopSpace, and is not documented in the `pgfmanual` whereas many other libraries go back to the creators or maintainers of Ti*k*Z and are thus tied to the pgfmanual.

Comment: @marmot Not in File List, but il the log there is `File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)` for calc.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm asking because of a user which uses Overleaf, looking in the dtx file in that case is difficult.

Comment: If the code has a version typeout it could be coerced in to adding it to the file list but there is no version string in the tikzmark code not even in a comment, it has no version or date.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle A simple `texdoc tikzmark` on my machine gives me `v1.6 from 2018/10/18` .... what do you get?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, the only solution is to write to the author...

Comment: @marmot `texdoc` ?  what a radical notion I just looked at  `tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex` in emacs ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This shows once more that one should not use emacs.... ;-)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes, `texdoc` gives you the documentation. (I am still not sure I understand the question. We agree that `\listfiles` does not give you the version of any library, do we? This suggests that you may want to resort to other means. Looking at the documentation works, doesn't it?)

Comment: But then "Invoke `texdoc tikzmark`" is a valid answer to your question (or can't overleaf users access the manual of the current version of the libraries/packages they are using?)?

Comment: @marmot I think they cannot

Comment: Revised answer: "Invoke `texdoc tikzmark`, and if you are using overleaf, quit overleaf and then invoke `texdoc tikzmark`". ;-) (According to [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_packages_do_you_support%3F) they are using the 2016 version of TeXLive....)

Comment: If there's a way that I can add version information to the file so that it gets logged via either `\listfiles` or the log file, please do tell me what that should be.

Comment: @LoopSpace I will be very happy to remove my answer below if you want to write one.

Comment: @marmot The point of my remark is that I suspect that there isn't an answer (at least, for users of overleaf) because I don't provide that information in the file that gets actually loaded (`tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex`).  However, I don't know the right way to provide that information (as it isn't included via `\usepackage`) hence if someone *does* know, I'd be grateful and add it to the next release.

Comment: @LoopSpace The `\ProvidesPackage` macro does that. For instance: `\ProvidesPackage{tikzmark}[2018-10-20 <version> TikZ mark library]`. But it's not loaded by `\usepackage`, so I guess it should be `\ProvidesFile`.

Comment: @LoopSpace I do not know, but there seem to be some line `\ProvidesFileRCS{tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex}` in the tikz libraries, and this makes use of stuff defined in `pgfrcs.code.tex` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for the hint.  I'll put that in the next version.

Comment: @LoopSpace You're welcome :) However I think marmot's suggestion is better. PGF has it's own file version handling system, and the `\ProvidesPackageRCS` macro seems to be a wrapper around `\ProvidesPackage`. I'd try that first.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'll have a play around with the variations and see what I can come up with.  Thanks for all the pointers.

Comment: Hey! Regarding your last edit: Overleaf **should never** replace any LaTeX distribution because the last has the latest updates and you can have different outputs.

Comment: @manooooh They do not do it, the date of your project identifies the distribution to use. My edit means that since I don't have a distribution tool on Overleaf I can't find the version simply typing `texdoc` on my terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had [similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491224/can-i-get-the-output-of-a-command-line-program-with-tex-using-e-g-read18) trying to find the Inkscape version used on Overleaf. Following this, I found the following approach:

---

First, you can use

```
\input|"texdoc -l tikzmark"
```

to get the texmf path, which already tells us a bit about the TeX Live version. Currently, Overleaf produces

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf
```

so they are using some 2017 version of TeX Live.

---

At this point I wanted to just include (the first page of) the documentation via `graphicx` or `pdfpages` to include the manual into the document, but that didn't work. I also tried to copy the manual file to the project directory using `cp` with no luck. Trying to use `inkscape` (which can be used to convert `.svg` files to `.pdf` in Overleaf*) to do the same (using the `-A` or `-e` option) did not succeed either. Seems like the have their system secured against mischief of this sort..

<sup><sub>* I don't know where the `.pdf` and `.pdf_tex` files are put when doing this (via the `svg` package). The user doesn't seem to have access to them. Having this information may reveal another route to do this in the right directory, where the permissions are different.</sub></sup>

---

What we do have access to, however, is the `tikzmark` source code. We can just print it using

```
\verbatiminput{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/source/latex/tikzmark/tikzmark.dtx}
```

(or one of the listing packages). And, lo and behold, some pages down we find the version:

```
% \date{v1.3~from 2017/06/01}
```

---

As pointed out by Phelype Oleinik in the comments, we can use `kpsewhich` to directly obtain the path to the `.dtx` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef\filepath{|"kpsewhich tikzmark.dtx"}{}
\verbatiminput{\filepath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that `|` thingy. You could, however, use `kpsewhich` instead and find the source directly: `\input|"kpsewhich tikzmark.dtx"`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Thanks for the hint. I improved the MWE accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

This is a pretty stupid check, but it works :)

[According to CTAN](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/tikzmark), there were three versions of `tikzmark`, so probably no one (including Overleaf users) has a version other than these three.

These three versions were released on 2016, 2017, and 2018. Luckily I could have access to all three of them. Comparing the sources, I found macros which are/are not present in each version. The following macro checks the existence of these macros and prints the version date:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\tikzmarkversion{%
  \@ifundefined{tikzmark@inside}%
    {2016-04-09}%
    {%
      \@ifundefined{tikzmarknode}%
        {2017-06-02}%
        {2018-10-20}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    I have Ti\emph{k}Zmark version \tikzmarkversion

    Something with \tikzmarknode{A}{TikZ Mark}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[<-, red] (A) -- ++(1,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in my machine it prints:

> [image]

and Overleaf reports: `I have TikZmark version 2017-06-02`.

The other versions complained about `\tikzmarknode` not existing, but the version date came out correct.

---

**Update:** I got the archived versions of `tikzmark` the frozen TeXLive versions back to 2013. The first appearance of `tikzmark` in TeXLive was in 2013. This release remained unchanged for 3 years. It was updated in TeXLive 2016 and was kept unchanged in TeXLive 2017. The third update was for TeXLive 2018. Thus a more fitting check is (until today, of course):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tikzmarkversion{%
  \@ifundefined{tikzmark@inside}%
    {TL 2013--2015}%
    {%
      \@ifundefined{tikzmarknode}%
        {TL 2016--2017}%
        {TL >2018}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

Of course this shows only frozen versions of TeXLive. The package might have been updated twice in a single year, so a version in between might exist somewhere which was overwritten and did not live to the freeze. There might have been many un-annouced updates as moewe said, so it's hard to know for sure. However, I'd go for this second test because usually if one doesn't have the current TeXLive, their version is the frozen one, so this one is probably more certain than CTAN's announcements.

And Overleaf reports `I have TikZmark version TL 2016–2017` in this one (which fits their claim of using TeXLive 2016 :).

I guess I'm a `tikzmark` historian now :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX I just tested and Overleaf reports `I have TikZmark version 2017-06-02`...

Comment: Sneaky! (and some more characters)

Comment: Nice detective work. But note that a package author can instruct CTAN to conduct a "silent" update, which means that the new version will not be announced and is not logged on its `ctan-ann` page. This is sometimes done for minor updates, but some packages like `biblatex` (yes, I only know that one) have not been announced for a very long time (don't know why): https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/biblatex, that could give a slightly incorrect pcture of the version history. I also noticed that https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/biblatex-ext doesn't show all announced versions (v0.6, v0.7), either.

Answer (score 6):

Provided you have a local TeX installation, a simple look at the manual reveals the version. E.g. on my Mac all I have to do is to type

```
 texdoc tikzmark
```

on the console to find out that my machine is blessed (I really mean blessed here!) with `v1.6 from 2018/10/18`.

If you do not have a LaTeX installation since you are working with overleaf, say, I have no clue. However, I feel that there should be an answer to the question

> How can one access the manuals of the version of a package that is used on overleaf?

yet it might be that the overleaf help center (and not this site) says more about this. At least I have nothing to say about this (and would like to argue that if some company bases its services on freely available packages, the very least this company should do is to make it easy for their users to get the information on the package version).