How do I make the text bend along the function using tikz if possible?
I am trying to label my diagram with the equation but I would love to make it bend along the equation. I haven't quite figured it out. I am hoping there is a solution involving tikz because it is what I am comfortable with but happy to use nodes if it's easier.
This is what I have so far. Thank you for your help.
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,scale=0.95]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        xlabel = \(x\),
        ylabel = \(y\),
        samples=250,
        xtick={},
        ytick={},
        ymin=-25,ymax=12,
        xmax=6,
        ticks=none,
        grid=both,
        xlabel style={right},
        ylabel style={above},
        enlargelimits
    ]
        \addplot[
            color=red,
            thick,
            line width=1.15pt,
            <->,
            >={Triangle[length=1.5mm, width=1.5mm]},
            domain=-7:4 
        ]{x^2+3*x-18} node[above] {$y=(x-3)(x+6)$};
        \draw[] (0,0) node[below right=1mm] {$0$};
        \draw[fill=red] (3,0) circle (2.5pt) node[red,above right=1mm] {$3$};
        \draw[fill=red] (-6,0) circle (2.5pt) node[red,above left=1mm] {$-6$};
        \draw[fill=red] (0,-18) circle (2.5pt) node[red,right=1mm] {$-18$};
        \draw[fill=red] (-1.5,-20.25) circle (2.5pt);
        \draw[red,dashed,line width=1.15pt] (-1.5,0) -- (-1.5,-20.25) -- (0,-20.25); 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



Did you check, whether or not your posted code will compile? If not, which it doesn't, please add what's missing. Thank you (May I remind you of your own comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713201/cross-multiplying-factorisation-diagram#comment1772606_713201 ?)

Since you know the function in this case, you can calculate its derivative and therefore calculate the angle in your points which would allow you to use rotate=<angle> on the nodes. However, your axes are differently scaled so this will need some adjustments (or you need axis eqal). Another option would be to use the pos key on the plot directly but this needs you to guess the position (they are not linearly related to the x value).

Approaches:

Guessing the positions. (They are not linear to the x value.)
Taking inspiration from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88421/16595 we can combinate the fillbetween library and place a node at the end of the part of plot that ended at the vertical of the x value.

Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, pgfplots.fillbetween} %%% 2.
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
%%% Common styles/settings
\tikzset{
  plot dot/.style={
    shape=circle, thin, draw=black, fill=red,
    inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+5pt},
  plot label/.style={
    text=red, fill=white, fill opacity=.75, text opacity=1,
    inner sep=+.15em, outer sep=2.5pt+\pgflinewidth}}
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={
    declare function={f(\x) = \x^2+3*\x-18;},
    axis lines = middle, xlabel = \(x\), ylabel = \(y\), samples=250,
    xtick=, ytick=, ticks=none, grid=both,
    ymin=-25, ymax=12, xmax=6,
    xlabel style={right}, ylabel style={above},
    enlargelimits},
  my plot/.style={
    color=red, thick, line width=1.15pt, <->, domain=-7:4,
    >={Triangle[length=1.5mm, width=1.5mm]}}}

\pgfplotsset{
  label at x/deco/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{%%% 2.
    name path=my plot,
    execute at end plot visualization/.append={
      \path[name path=vert](#2,0|-{rel axis cs:0,0})--(#2,0|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
      \path[intersection segments={of=my plot and vert, sequence=L1}] node[plot dot]{}
         [postaction=decorate, decoration={name=markings, mark=at position 1 with
           {\node[plot label, #1, transform shape] {$#3$};}}];}}}
\begin{document}

%%% 1. Guess the positions
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[my plot]{f(x)} node[above] {$y=(x-3)(x+6)$}
  foreach \pos/\anchor/\l in {.162/above/-6, .5/below/-18, 1-.162/above/3}{
    node[plot dot, pos=\pos] {}
    node[plot label, \anchor, pos=\pos, sloped] {$\l$}};
\node[below right=1mm] at (0,0) {$0$};
\draw[red, dashed, line width=1.15pt] (-1.5, 0) |- (0, -20.25);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%%% 2. Calculate intersection and mark via decoration
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[
  my plot,
  label at x/deco/.list={above/-6/-6, below/-1.5/-18, above/3/3}]
  {f(x)} node[above] {$y=(x-3)(x+6)$};
\node[below right=1mm] at (0,0) {$0$};
\draw[red, dashed, line width=1.15pt] (-1.5, 0) |- (0, -20.25);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output

