# Problems with package tikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've switched to Ubuntu and the following code does not run, although it does on Mac OS. I have attached a screenshot with the logs.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}



\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l | c | r }
    \sffamily
    &      A    &   B  \\ \hline
     1 & $\tikzmarknode{a11}{r_{1A}}$~ &   ~$\tikzmarknode{a12}{r_{1B}}$ \\ \hline
    2 & $\tikzmarknode{a21}{r_{2A}}$~  & ~$\tikzmarknode{a22}{r_{BA}}$ \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[stealth-stealth,blue] (a11.north east) -- (a12.north west)
node[midway,above,scale=0.4,black] (dAB) {$d_{AB}$};
\draw[-stealth,blue] (a21.south east) -- (a22.south west);
\draw[-stealth,blue] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] (dAB.south|-a22);
\draw[stealth-stealth] (a11.east) -- (a21.east)
node[pos=0.5,above right,scale=0.4,black] (d12) {$d_{12}$};
\draw[-stealth] (d12.north) to[out=0,in=180] ([yshift=-1ex]a12.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date TeX distribution?

Comment: TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1/dev
Copyright 2018 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.

Comment: Please provide the log file. `\tikzmarknode` is a newly added command, out-of-date distributions may not have it.

Comment: I thought the log file was in the screenshot I have added in the description. Where do I find it, then? Hey, thank you for your help!

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474934/121799) you can learn how to find out what tikzmark version you have.

Comment: v1.3 from 2017/06/01

Comment: I run this to update it: `tlmgr update tikzmark`

Comment: This is what I get:     (running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TeX Live 2018 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: no updates available