# Can I get the output of a command line program with TeX (using e.g. \read18)?

Tags: tex-core, shell-escape, command-line

Say I want to call some external program using `\write18`, which returns some text to the command line. Can I get that text from inside TeX?

As an example

```
> inkscape -V
```

returns the version of the inkscape installation, in my case

```
Inkscape 0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)
```

How can I retrieve this information using TeX?

(Note: I am running TeX on Windows, but would like the solution to be system independent.)

Comment: `\input|"inkscape -V"` should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `\input|"inkscape -V"` (requires `-shell-escape`). However, I suggest defining a macro so that you can also manipulate the output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\CatchFileDef{\inkscapebanner}{|"inkscape -V"}{}

\begin{document}

\inkscapebanner

\end{document}
```

[image]

An example of manipulation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\CatchFileDef{\inkscapebanner}{|"inkscape -V"}{}
\makeatletter
\def\@getinkscapeversioninfo#1 #2 #3, #4\@nil{%
  \def\inkscapeversion{#2}%
  \def\inkscapebuild{#3}%
  \def\inkscaperelease{#4}%
}
\expandafter\@getinkscapeversioninfo\inkscapebanner\@nil
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\inkscapebanner\par
\inkscapeversion\par
\inkscapebuild\par
\inkscaperelease\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

The mandatory `expl3` version:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \inkscapebanner
\tl_new:N \inkscapeversion
\tl_new:N \inkscapebuild
\tl_new:N \inkscaperelease

\sys_shell_get:nnN { inkscape~-V } { \char_set_catcode_space:n { `~ } } \inkscapebanner
\seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } \inkscapebanner
\tl_set:Nx \inkscapeversion { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }
\tl_set:Nx \inkscapebuild { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 3 } }
\tl_set:Nx \inkscapebuild { \tl_range:Nnn \inkscapebuild { 1 } { -1 } }
\tl_set:Nx \inkscaperelease { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 4 } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\inkscapebanner\par
\inkscapeversion\par
\inkscapebuild\par
\inkscaperelease\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the fact that `\input|"inkscape -V"` works a TeX feature or a side effect of its implementation? A search through the TeXbook yielded nothing and this isn't really how I thought the pipe command worked either (since a pipe usually directs output from its left to the command to its right). Why does this work?

Comment: @schtandard It's a “TeX Live addition” added a few years ago.

Comment: @schtandard You can find it with `texdoc web2c`, section 4.5

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! (Actually, MiKTeX doesn't find anything when asking `texdoc web2c`, but the manual is also [available online](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/web2c.html#Shell-escapes).)